# Editing a recorded macro to filter for three variables

Tags: excel, vba

I had an initial process, where I would filter values in an array based on conditions (date, money group and measure) and paste into another sheet. I would then run code to copy these values based on conditions and paste into a separate worksheet.

I want to eliminate the manual bit where I filter myself and paste into another sheet. I recorded the manual process that I use and my plan was to insert a sheet of the same name so the remainder of the initial code would work as normal.

The problem is that I want to read the dates on the worksheet that I am pasting into, use these as variables and then filter my values on the worksheet I am getting data from and pasting into another sheet.

Here is the code with comments:

```
Sub Actual()

Dim rw As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim rpt_nm As String
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim dt1, dt2, dt3 As Date
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TAmt, VAmt, UAmt, OAmt As Double

Worksheets("PAct").Range("G1").Activate

Let rw = ActiveCell
Let rpt_nm = Range("k1").Value
Let dt1 = Cells(rw, 1)
Let dt2 = Cells(rw + 1, 1)
Let dt3 = Cells(rw + 2, 1)

' Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\2. 2019 Legacy.xlsx"
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & rpt_nm)
With wb2
    .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets("Actual Input").Name = "VBA Input"
End With

'This is the macro I recorded in sheet I am trying to copy from
Sheets("Actual Input").Activate
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=IF(LEN(RC[-1])=9,DATE(RIGHT(RC[-1],4),LEFT(RC[-1],1),MID(RC[-1],3,2)),DATE(RIGHT(RC[-1],4),LEFT(RC[-1],2),MID(RC[-1],4,2)))"
Range("E2").Select         'Formatting on previous lines was my clumsy attempt to try and change text formats to dates using excel
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E721")
Range("E2:E721").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("E2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                 :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("D1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("E1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$721").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Net"
****ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$721").AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:= _
                 xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "7/31/2019", 1, "8/31/2019", 1, "9/30/2019") 'This is the place where I want to remove the specific dates selected and use variables
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$721").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="5M="       ‘Everytime I try and replace these values with dt1, dt2 and dt3 the filter will not select anything and there is no data****
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                 :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("I3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/1000000"
Range("I3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I3:I17")
Range("I3:I17").Select
ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$721").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1M-4.99M"
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Range("K2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                 :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("S3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/1000000"
Range("S3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S3:S17")
Range("S3:S17").Select
ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$721").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1M<"
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Range("U2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                 :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=4
Range("AC3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/1000000"
Range("AC3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AC3:AC17")
Range("AC3:AC17").Select
'This is where the macro recorder ends

For z = 0 To 2
    For i = 0 To 2

        wb2.Worksheets("VBA Input").Activate

        VAmt = Cells(3 + (i * 5), 9 + (z * 10))
        UAmt = Cells(4 + (i * 5), 9 + (z * 10)) + Cells(5 + (i * 5), 9 + (z * 10))
        TAmt = Cells(6 + (i * 5), 9 + (z * 10))
        OAmt = Cells(7 + (i * 5), 9 + (z * 10))

        wb.Worksheets("PAct").Activate
        Cells(rw + i, 16 + (z * 5)) = TAmt
        Cells(rw + i, 17 + (z * 5)) = VAmt
        Cells(rw + i, 18 + (z * 5)) = UAmt
        Cells(rw + i, 19 + (z * 5)) = OAmt

    Next
Next

End Sub
```

If you think there is a better approach, particularly in regards to the recorded macro, let me know.

Comment: One problem with recorded macros is they use `select` like there's no tomorrow and you [really want to avoid that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note:

- **The Select & Activate Method**: you want to avoid using the Select/Activate methods. Typically they're auto generated when making a Macro recording however when writing VBA programs in Excel, it is best to avoid them as it makes a codebase unnecessarily big and affects performance. You can get away with referencing a particular cell/range using [Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.range) and running procedures off of it as a reference.
- **Variable & Object Declarations**: it's best to declare you variables/objects closest to where they're being used as a reader can easily see where and what the item is being used for. A huge codeblock of declarations is pretty hard to read when the variable uses are several lines down the codebase.
- **Copy/Paste Methods**: avoid using copy and paste. Refer to specific Range/Cell values instead. For example, say that you want to copy the value from Sheet1 cell A1 to Sheet2 cell A2. You would have something like this:

```
    Dim src As Range, dest As Range

    Set src = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    Set dest = Sheet2.Range("A2")

    dest.Value2 = src.Value2
```

- **Sheet Referencing**: I prefer to use worksheet code names as opposed to worksheet names that can easily be changed by a user and break a VBA procedure. Rather than getting into the details here, feel free to take a look at [The Spreadsheet Guru site](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-guide-to-referencing-excel-worksheet-tabs) lists the several ways of referring to worksheets.

Welcome to the world of VBA! It's a great programming language to know especially for knowledge workers that spend an extensive time in Excel. There's plenty of support on the web when you find yourself lost on the journey.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

So generally, you'll want to use recorded macros to get an idea of which functions you would use to do something. Recorded macros really aren't great for generating dynamic code. To read the dates of the workbook you are pasting into, use WorkSheets("SheetName").Range("A1").Value, for example. Then you can use that date to filter the code you will copy over.

Take it step by step and don't get overwhelmed. There's a ton of unnecessary junk in that recorded macro.